# Quickly navigating through an ASP.NET MVC app in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

I spent a fair bit of time developing Rails apps in VIM with an amazing plugin called [Rails.Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567)

Whenever I wanted to navigate to a Model I would hit:

<kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>:Rmodel topic[enter]</kbd> to find the topic model.

In this mode tab completion works so I could hit <kbd>:Rmo[tab] to[tab][enter]</kbd>

(for an added bonus <kbd>:RSmodel topic[enter]</kbd> would split the window and open the model in the split

Or <kbd>:RTmodel topic[enter]</kbd> would open it in a new tab)

Similar shortcuts exist for navigation to javascript, css, views, helpers, controllers and so on.

Is there a similar plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that would allow me to approximate this kind of behavior, allowing me to navigate my MVC project with **keyboard** shortcuts **only**?

Answer (score 4):

To navigate to a method/class/type definition that is visible on your current screen (I.E. the method/class/type is properly being used in a piece of code you're viewing), place your cursor on it and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>.

To navigate to a class/method/property/field etc. anywhere in your project, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> then start typing to search for it. The results will auto filter.

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> search uses the same new search standards as IntelliSense in 2010. So typing `MSA` in the search will return `MailServerAddress` etc.

I'm not sure there exists anything beyond the normal search functionality for CSS/JS/Views.

### Update

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> Does indeed filter by file names. So searching for views by file name works.

Comment: Remember that in VS2010 the Ctrl+, dialog works with Pascal casing so if searching for MyModelClass all you need to type is MMC (must be in caps for this to work)

Comment: Is there a way to restrict ctrl + , so it only includes files?

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize the shortcut keys to navigate from the controller to the views and back http://ebersys.blogspot.com/2011/05/visual-studio-aspnet-mvc-flip-quickly.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. It opens a search box that lets you search for classes, files, methods, etc.